# After giving superuser permission it gives adb:not found

Tags: android

After Typing su then I Use ADB Push Command, Its Says ADB not found, So I  Cant Use The Push Command.. How Do I Use It in # mode ?

Answer (score 0):

if you are in superuser mode you dont need the adb preface, su uses always adb

Comment: but how can use adb pull with # mode.

Comment: just du pull without the adb preface